# how to add social share button in angular 4

Tags: html, angular

I have run the command "npm install --save ng2-social-share".

and then add into app.module.ts :-

```
import { CeiboShare } from 'ng2-social-share';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CeiboShare
  ]
});
```

and then i add into my home.component.ts :-

```
import { CeiboShare } from 'ng2-social-share';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  directives: [CeiboShare]
})
```

webpack: Compiling...
ERROR in src/app/home/home.component.ts(16,3): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ selector: string; templateUrl: string; styleUrls: string[]; directives: typeof CeiboShare[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'directives' does not exist in type 'Component'.

Date: 2018-02-27T09:02:42.288Z - Hash: bedb972b22f9a72ebb59 - Time: 2832ms
5 unchanged chunks
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 367 kB [initial] [rendered]

webpack: Compiled successfully.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: You don't need to include the directive at the component level, you just need to import it in the imports section of your module

Comment: If i remove directive. still getting confuse what should i do next to integrate social share in my component

Answer (score 0):

The simple way for you is to  import in your app.modules.ts like this
1) import {CeiboShare} from 'ng2-social-share';

```
@NgModule({
```

declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CeiboShare
]
})

2) and then in your  home.component.ts

you need to just only define the url sharing link and image url sharing if you want like this:

```
//vars used only for example, put anything you want :)
```

public repoUrl = 'https://www.egozola.com';
  public imageUrl = 'https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/10674541?v=3&s=200';

3. the in your  home.component.html the you can call sharing easily like this

   button ceiboShare  [facebook]="{u: repoUrl}">Facebook
   Linkedin
   Google Plus
   Twitter
   Pinterest
4. good all thing is working well

Comment: you can't use ng2-social-share as problem is with package that it is not supportable during building of project for angular version greater than 2 as directives are no more part of components decorator and even if you declare it in declarations of module then your app supports package on your local but when you build up the app for production you ends up with an error.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to use these functions on your typescript file and call it from the template.

**Providing here 5 Social Media Share** - Facebook, Pinterest, Twitter, GooglePlus, LinkedIn

```
  // Facebook share won't work if your shareUrl is localhost:port/abc, it should be genuine deployed url 
  shareOnFacebook(shareUrl: string) {
    shareUrl = encodeURIComponent(shareUrl);
    window.open(`https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=${shareUrl}`, 'sharer');
  }

  shareOnPinterest(shareUrl: string, img: string, desc: string) {
    shareUrl = encodeURIComponent(shareUrl);
    img = encodeURIComponent(img);
    desc = encodeURIComponent(desc);
    window.open(`https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button?url=${shareUrl}&media=${img}&description=${desc}`, 'sharer');
  }

  shareOnTwitter(shareUrl: string, desc: string) {
    shareUrl = encodeURIComponent(shareUrl);
    desc = encodeURIComponent(desc);
    window.open(`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=${shareUrl}&text=${desc}`, 'sharer');
  }

  shareOnGooglePlus(shareUrl: string) {
    shareUrl = encodeURIComponent(shareUrl);
    window.open(`https://plus.google.com/share?url=${shareUrl}`, 'sharer');
  }
  
  // LinkedIn share won't work if your shareUrl is localhost:port/abc, it should be genuine deployed url
  shareOnLinkedIn(shareUrl: string, title: string, summary: string) {
    shareUrl = encodeURIComponent(shareUrl);
    window.open(`https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url=${shareUrl}&title=${title}&summary=${summary}`, 'sharer');
  }
```

Hope this will help you or somebody else.
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

remove that `directives :  [CeiboShare]` from @component decorator. It is not supported in angular 4 and you don't even need to import it into your component. Just Import into Ngmodule as below,

```
import { CeiboShare } from 'ng2-social-share';

@NgModule({
 imports: [
  CeiboShare.forRoot()
 ]
});
```

This would suffice to get it working in any component as attribute directives.